# multiple css classes weird behavior

Tags: css, class, styles

I had a class like this

```
.lifetime .containerrow
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
}
```

I needed to make the text in some of the elements bold so I did this:

```
.lifetime .containerrow .info
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

this didn't work but this did:

```
.lifetime.containerrow.info
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Why?
Isn't is the same thing?
Thanks
Don't know css that well

Comment: In the first case you apply de style to the class info who is into another element with the class containerrow who is into another element with the class lifetime.
In the second case you apply the style over a element with the three classes.

Comment: I found an `answer` in your question `ACCIDENTALLY!!!!!` Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct behaviour. `.class1.class2.class3` matches elements that have all three classes. `.class1 .class2 .class3` matches an element of `.class3` inside an element of `.class2` inside an element of `.class1`.

If you want to apply the same style to three separate classes, you need to separate them with commas (e.g. `.class1, .class2, .class3 { font-weight: bold; }`)

Answer (score 0):

```
.lifetime .containerrow .info
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

means an element with a class of .info that is nested inside .containerrow that is nested inside .lifetime

```
.lifetime.containerrow.info
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

means an element with the classes .lifetime, .containerrow and .info

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to apply a bold font-weight to multiple classes:

```
.lifetime,
.containerrow,
.info
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

You have to separate classes with a comma to select different classes on different elements yet apply the same style.

With the selector: `.lifetime .containerrow .info` you were selecting one element that had the `.info` class that was a child of `.containerrow` which in turn was a child of `.lifetime`.